# How to assign a list to list objects with loop in R?

Tags: r, list, loops

Consider that we have five list objects:

```
# create the lists
for (i in 1:5) {
 assign(paste0('my_list', i), list(first = NA, second = NA))
}

# then, we have my_list1 - my_list5
> ls()
[1] "i" "my_list1" "my_list2" "my_list3" "my_list4" "my_list5"
```

Here, I want to assign a list to the "first" of each list. That is, what I want to do is

```
my_list1$first <- list(hello = c(1, 2, 3), world = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
my_list2$first <- list(hello = c(1, 2, 3), world = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
my_list3$first <- list(hello = c(1, 2, 3), world = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
my_list4$first <- list(hello = c(1, 2, 3), world = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
my_list5$first <- list(hello = c(1, 2, 3), world = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

I thought that the following code may work:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  assign(paste0('my_list', i, '[[1]]'), list(hello = c(1, 2, 3), world = c(1, 2, 3, 4)))
}
```

But, you know, the command just makes the other lists named `my_list1[[1]]`, `my_list1[[1]]` and so on:

```
> ls()
 [1] "i" "my_list1" "my_list1[[1]]" "my_list2" "my_list2[[1]]" "my_list3" "my_list3[[1]]" "my_list4"     
 [9] "my_list4[[1]]" "my_list5" "my_list5[[1]]"
```

So, how can I do the job I want with loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `get()` each list, manipulate it, then re-`assign()`:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  l <- get(paste0('my_list', i))
  l[[1]] <- list(hello = c(1, 2, 3), world = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
  assign(paste0('my_list', i), l)
}

my_list1
```

```
$first
$first$hello
[1] 1 2 3

$first$world
[1] 1 2 3 4


$second
[1] NA
```

That said, storing your lists in a superordinate list rather than in the global environment would make them easier to work with:

```
# create the lists 
my_lists <- list()
for (i in 1:5) {
  my_lists[[paste0('my_list', i)]] <- list(first = NA, second = NA)
}

for (i in 1:5) {
  my_lists[[i]][[1]] <- list(hello = c(1, 2, 3), world = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
}

my_lists[['my_list1']]
```

```
$first
$first$hello
[1] 1 2 3

$first$world
[1] 1 2 3 4


$second
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Those lists can be accessed from `.GlobalEnv` by name:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  .GlobalEnv[[paste0('my_list', i)]]$first <- list(hello = c(1, 2, 3), world = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
}
my_list1
# $first
# $first$hello
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $first$world
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# 
# $second
# [1] NA
```

But it is better to hold all those `my_list*` in a single list so that you can easily manipulate them later.